# JavaFX 8 JVM remains after exit

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, javafx-8

I have created a JavaFX application, and noticed that after I close the main stage, the following happens:

- The Applications "stop" method is called
- The main method continues
- After the program leaves the main method, the JVM can not close

I do not create any threads (explicitly not, at least). The threads that are running at this point are (from the debug console):

- InvokeLaterDispatcher
- Prism Font Disposer
- 'pool-2-thread-1' (I don't know what this is - ThreadPoolExecutor parts are in its stacktrace)
- HSQLDB Timer (I'm using a HSQLDB file db on the development/debug system)
- FX Access Thread (Visual Debugger)
- Abandoned connection cleanup thread

Which of these threads can stop the JVM from closing? I would think that all of these should be daemon threads...

Here is my Application code:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {       
    final FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Main.fxml"));
    Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/Styles.css");

    //... Scene/stage setup here
    stage.show();
}

@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    super.stop();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Adding a System.exit(0); on the end of the stop() method fixes this, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution to the problem...
Any ideas?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are using a HSQLDB, you don't show the code where you initialize it. In your stop() method, close that connection.

Comment: I use JPA, and the only thing I'm storing is the EntityManagerFactory, what I create with Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory().
Is this a problem?

Comment: the EntityManagerFactroy has a `close()` method, Javadoc for that says: _Close the factory, releasing any resources that it holds. After a factory instance is closed, all methods invoked on it will throw an IllegalStateException, except for isOpen, which will return false. Once an EntityManagerFactory has been closed, all its entity managers are considered to be in the closed state._